# Saving two slightly different status for a table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a reservation table (a user fills out a form to request a reservation).

It has two parts that need to be confirmed. isReservationAccepted (decline,accept,waiting) and hasReservationBeenSent (sent, declined, waiting)

Not sure how to structure my table, thinking about making a lookup table for each column, or maybe just creating them as int, and having 1 = accepted/sent, 2 = declined, 3 = waiting.

How should I create a status table for these conditions?

Comment: Both ways are fine, they'll both work. Nobody can guess what your needs will be in the future. I would be tempted to use a 3rd option: A `reservation_accepted` boolean column, set to `true` (accepted) `false` (declined) or `null` (waiting). Ditto for a `reservation_sent` column.

Comment: You could have a generic lookup table capable of storing values/descriptions for a variety of lists. You would just need a column to differentiate the sets, `lookup_type` or something similar. Obviously, going forward, this would make things much more maintainable than having to create a separate lookup table each time, and there would be no need to change the code if you wanted different values/descriptions in future. I've seen this kind of generic solution for lookups used in many applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a generic structure that you can use:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[LookUpTypes]    Script Date: 12/06/2013 10:13:51 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LookUpTypes](
    [LookUpTypeID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LookUpTypeDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LookUpTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LookUpTypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
--************************************************
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LookUpValues](
    [LookUpValueID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LookUpTypeID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LookUpValue] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LookUpValueDescription] [varchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LookUpValues] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LookUpValueID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LookUpValues]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LookUpValues_LookUpTypes] FOREIGN KEY([LookUpTypeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LookUpTypes] ([LookUpTypeID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LookUpValues] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LookUpValues_LookUpTypes]
GO
```

Comment: So you have your LookUpVlaues which will have 1,2,3, which relate to a description, got that.  How does this relate back to the reservation table? Should I keep two columns that both link to LookUpValues in the reservation table?

Comment: Yes, based on your description it sounds like you will need two columns in the reservation table that link to the LookUpValues table. Keep in mind that this might look like too much "overhead" for the simple scenario you describe but the benefit is that this handles all lookup types/values you need now or that you will need in the future (list of countries, list of states, various status lists etc.) AND you only need to create one single form to manage (add/update/delete) all your lookups.

Comment: You are right, I thought it did look like too much overhead, but the ability to use it for any sort of list is definitely good!